# Periodic task on Tomcat server

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I need a java routine that runs every night on a tomcat server. Any ideas on how I can do this?
I try to do something like an event/schedule in mysql

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Quartz scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)

Comment: if it is more like a script or something, you can use a linux cron job (I assume you are on linux, there is an equivalent for Windows as well)

Comment: Do you need the task to run *in* Tomcat, or just on the machine that hosts it?

Comment: I need that my application compares every night a date registered with the current date if they coincide that execute another routine

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Answer (score 1):

It's been some time since this question was asked, but recently I had a similar problem and would like to share my solution.

What I did was just create a ServletContextListener that creates a `ScheduledExecutorService`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

@WebListener
public class BackgroundJobManager implements ServletContextListener {    
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        this.scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        this.scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new JobClass(), 1, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

This code executes `JobClass` once a day. 
`JobClass` must implement `java.lang.Runnable`

Answer (score 0):

A pure java solution would be to use [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). If pure java is not required, I recommend a simple `cron` job.